# fetch resultset in chunks in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Let's say I have a query that return 10000 rows. Is it possible to configure this query in SQL Server so that it returns the result in chunks with 1000 rows each? So my application receives 1000 rows, processes them, and while it does that SQL Server is working to send the next 1000 rows etc.?

This is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server gives you a result set, which is delivered as a network packet stream (assuming you use TCP/IP to connect to the server).

So if you want to be really hardcore, you can implement the wire protocol to access SQL Server over the net and then work on the TCP stream. This would be a major work however and is not really advisable.

Another possibility would be to query not once, but to use several queries, where each one gets a certain "window" of your resultset. This is called "server side paging". See [this](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070628.htm) article for a description of how it's done.

Another method would be to use a stream based access on the client side. For example, if you use ADO.NET as client, you can use the SqlDataReader to get one row at a time (in the background the data is still delivered in chunks over the network, but that is transparent to you). But that depends on the client you use, which you have not specified.

Comment: would there be any sense in having server side paging and making several calls just to at the client side putting them in a list? Instead of just making one huge call and returning that list, we make smaller calls that append the result to a list and then return that one. Could that improve response time and/or memory usage? So there's really no processing in between the smaller calls.

Comment: @KTrum: If you just want to build a list of the records on the client and you have to wait until the list is complete, then server side paging is not useful. If you can start processing already while waiting for the next page, you reduce latency. If you can do pagewise processing for a small result, paging reduces memory consumption.